# Sum of distances from a point to all other points

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, euclidean-distance, pdist

I have two lists

`available_points = [[2,3], [4,5], [1,2], [6,8], [5,9], [51,35]]`

and

`solution = [[3,5], [2,1]]`

I'm trying to *pop* a point in `available_points` and *append* it to `solution` for which the sum of euclidean distances from that point, to all points in the `solution` is the greatest.

So, I would get this

`solution = [[3,5], [2,1], [51,35]]`

---

I was able to select the initial 2 furthest points like this, but not sure how to proceed.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

available_points = np.array([[2,3], [4,5], [1,2], [6,8], [5,9], [51,35]])

D = squareform(pdist(available_points)
I_row, I_col = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(D), D.shape)
solution = available_points[[I_row, I_col]]
```

which gives me

`solution = array([[1, 2], [51, 35]])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) -

```
In [1]: from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

In [2]: max_pt=available_points[cdist(available_points, solution).sum(1).argmax()]

In [3]: np.vstack((solution, max_pt))
Out[3]: 
array([[ 3,  5],
       [ 2,  1],
       [51, 35]])
```

Comment: Nice, cleaner solution then what I came up with. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the max function to find the maximum in a 'available_points'  list & then append the maximum of 'available_points' list to 'solution' list !
I am also attached the screenshot of the output !

```
available_points = [[2,3], [4,5], [1,2], [6,8], [5,9], [51,35]];
solution = [[3,5], [2,1]]
solution.append(max(available_points));
print(solution);
```

[image: output]

Comment: try to think about solution is [[100,100],[200,200]], the 'far' point will not be max of  available_points

Comment: This should not be used.  See Wen's comment.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tag `numpy`

```
import numpy as np 

solution=np.array(solution)
available_points=np.array(available_points)
l=[]
for x in solution:
    l.append(np.linalg.norm(available_points-x, keepdims=True,axis=1))


np.append(solution,[available_points[np.argmax(np.array(l).sum(0))]],axis=0)
Out[237]: 
array([[ 3,  5],
       [ 2,  1],
       [51, 35]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with using [`cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html)

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

d = cdist(solution, available_points)

distances = []

for q in range(len(available_points)):
    y = d[:,q]
    distances.append(sum(y))

# Largest Distance
max_point = available_points[distances.index(max(distances))]

# Update datasets
solution = np.append(solution, [max_point], axis=0)
universe = np.delete(available_points, max_index, 0)
```